# amcharts - different color per each bar

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm using AMCHARTS for graphs in my support system (where users can submit support tickets).

I created script for this bars:

https://www.amcharts.com/demos/clustered-bar-chart/

My graphs shoe, per each user, all his tickets separate by statuses

how can i set different colors per each status?

Example for status: "Waiting for support to reply"

Here is my script:

```
<!-- Resources -->
<script src="js/charts/core.js"></script>
<script src="js/charts/charts.js"></script>
<script src="js/charts/animated.js"></script>

<!-- Chart code -->
<script>
am4core.ready(function() {

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

 // Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);


// Add data
chart.data = [

    {
        "User": "Effi",
        "Waiting for support to reply" : 34, 
        "Waiting for customer to reply" : 33, 
        "Waiting for programmer to reply" : 42
    }               
    ,
    {
        "User": "Michal",
        "Waiting for support to reply" : 9,
        "Waiting for customer to reply" : 14, 
        "Waiting for programmer to reply" : 5
    }               

];

// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "User";
categoryAxis.numberFormatter.numberFormat = "#";
categoryAxis.renderer.inversed = true;
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 1;
categoryAxis.renderer.cellStartLocation = 0.1;
categoryAxis.renderer.cellEndLocation = 0.9;

var  valueAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis()); 
valueAxis.renderer.opposite = true;

// Create series
function createSeries(field, name) {
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
  series.dataFields.valueX = field;
  series.dataFields.categoryY = "User";
  series.name = name;
  series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{valueX}[/]";
  series.columns.template.height = am4core.percent(100);
  series.sequencedInterpolation = true;
  series.columns.template.propertyFields.fill = "color";

  var valueLabel = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
  valueLabel.label.text = "{valueX}";
  valueLabel.label.horizontalCenter = "left";
  valueLabel.label.dx = 10;
  valueLabel.label.hideOversized = false;
  valueLabel.label.truncate = false;

  var categoryLabel = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
  categoryLabel.label.text = "{name}";
  categoryLabel.label.horizontalCenter = "right";
  categoryLabel.label.dx = -10;
  categoryLabel.label.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
  categoryLabel.label.hideOversized = false;
  categoryLabel.label.truncate = false;
}

createSeries("Waiting for support to reply", "Waiting for support to reply"); 
createSeries("Waiting for customer to reply", "Waiting for customer to reply"); 
createSeries("Waiting for programmer to reply", "Waiting for programmer to reply")


}); // end am4core.ready()
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  specify the color directly as you create your series since it doesn't appear to be attached to any specific data outside of the series name. You can do this by setting the `fill` and `stroke` of the column template, for example:

```
 function createSeries(field, name, color) {
  // ...
  series.columns.template.fill = color;
  series.columns.template.stroke = color;
  // ...
 }

createSeries("Waiting for support to reply", "Waiting for support to reply", "#880088"); 
createSeries("Waiting for customer to reply", "Waiting for customer to reply", "#123456"); 
createSeries("Waiting for programmer to reply", "Waiting for programmer to reply", "#912100")
```

Demo below:

```js
am4core.ready(function() {

  // Themes begin
  am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
  // Themes end

  // Create chart instance
  var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);


  // Add data
  chart.data = [

    {
      "User": "Effi",
      "Waiting for support to reply": 34,
      "Waiting for customer to reply": 33,
      "Waiting for programmer to reply": 42
    },
    {
      "User": "Michal",
      "Waiting for support to reply": 9,
      "Waiting for customer to reply": 14,
      "Waiting for programmer to reply": 5
    }

  ];

  // Create axes
  var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
  categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "User";
  categoryAxis.numberFormatter.numberFormat = "#";
  categoryAxis.renderer.inversed = true;
  categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 1;
  categoryAxis.renderer.cellStartLocation = 0.1;
  categoryAxis.renderer.cellEndLocation = 0.9;

  var valueAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
  valueAxis.renderer.opposite = true;

  // Create series
  function createSeries(field, name, color) {
    var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
    series.dataFields.valueX = field;
    series.dataFields.categoryY = "User";
    series.name = name;
    series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{valueX}[/]";
    series.columns.template.height = am4core.percent(100);
    series.sequencedInterpolation = true;
    series.columns.template.fill = color;
    series.columns.template.stroke = color;

    var valueLabel = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
    valueLabel.label.text = "{valueX}";
    valueLabel.label.horizontalCenter = "left";
    valueLabel.label.dx = 10;
    valueLabel.label.hideOversized = false;
    valueLabel.label.truncate = false;

    var categoryLabel = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
    categoryLabel.label.text = "{name}";
    categoryLabel.label.horizontalCenter = "right";
    categoryLabel.label.dx = -10;
    categoryLabel.label.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
    categoryLabel.label.hideOversized = false;
    categoryLabel.label.truncate = false;
  }

  createSeries("Waiting for support to reply", "Waiting for support to reply", "#880088");
  createSeries("Waiting for customer to reply", "Waiting for customer to reply", "#123456");
  createSeries("Waiting for programmer to reply", "Waiting for programmer to reply", "#912100")


}); // end am4core.ready()
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```